# build python library with bazel

Tags: python, build, bazel

I would like to build part of [tensorflow_federated](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/) project and use it as an external dependency, namely [research](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/tree/master/tensorflow_federated/python/research) package. I built some files using bazel and I have them in bazel-bin. I would like to use them like a usual python package so that I can just import certain functions in other project, is that possible? If so how do I achieve it? I looked through some bazel tutorials for python but the amount of resources doesn't seem sufficient. I've never worked with bazel before so I am a bit lost, any advice would be greatly appreciated.